# Whirring wawawa noise at wheel speed

Tags: wheels, noise

2003 Honda Civic ex 212000 miles

Wuwuwu noise that gets louder and faster as speed increases, probably matching wheel rotation speed, can't tell if front or rear. Bearing? Wheel balance?

- [55 mph then decelerating](https://clyp.it/14l4hcxf)
- [slowing to a stop](https://clyp.it/dm4l2yzq)

Comment: Can you maybe post a sample of the noise? Wuwuwu isn’t exactly a good description hehe

Comment: @sjfklsdafjks possibly. I'm not sure how well it would record

Comment: @sjfklsdafjks Added sounds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the brief provided information, in my opinion these are the possibilities:

Most probably - wheel bearings. Often you can confirm this cause when the sound changes (or even disappears) when turning left or right.

I can also imagine other two following causes:

a) Tire issue (bump, low pressure, etc). However, this would most probably manifest itself not only by the noise but also by vibration which you don't mention.

b) Contact of the wheel with an alien object that somehow got stuck around the wheel - you can easily eliminate by looking around your wheels.

Comment: I don't think it changes when I turn but I'll pay more attention

Comment: It doesn't change when turning, it does change when I hit a bump and car moves up and down.  Added sound recordings

Comment: Mechanic confirmed it was a bearing

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a wheel bearing. The other test for this is to jack up the car and see if the wheel has play vertically, that is hold the tyre at 12 o clock and 6 o clock and wiggle, if there's lots of movement, or any clunks, probably a wheel bearing

Answer (score 1):

Based on the sound I would say tire issue. Sounds like the tire is slightly out of round with a little of uneven tread wear. If it were a bearing It would make a different noise. I read somewhere on this site or my own research online that a worn wheel bearing causes the ABS brake light to flash erratically. The reason is because the worn bearing affects the ground connection to the sensor. If it throws a code it tells you what bearing is buggered.